# Two sets of similar python code seem to act differently

Tags: python

Trying to figure out why I'm getting two different results here (one that is an error).  Here is the code that runs:

```
hta = 2.13
visitor_team_ratings = [21.53]
home_team_ratings = [None]
difference = []

for a, b in zip(visitor_team_ratings, home_team_ratings):
    if a and b:
        difference.append(a - (b + float(hta)))
    else:
        difference.append('NO RATING')
print(difference)
```

This prints out "NO RATING" but I'm hard pressed to understand why it does that.  None isn't the same thing as an empty list so why is python dropping down to the `else` statement.

Here is similar code that throws an error.  Same variables/list as the working code above:

```
if visitor_team_ratings and home_team_ratings:
    difference.append((visitor_team_ratings[0] - (home_team_ratings[0] + float(hta))))
else:
    difference.append('NO RATING')
print(difference)
```

The error is: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'float'`

I'm not sure I understand why one works and one doesn't.  And the one that does work, I'm not even sure I understand why it does that.  I've been using that 1st code block in my program for a while...

Comment: `if visitor_team_ratings and home_team_ratings:` should be `if visitor_team_ratings[0] and home_team_ratings[0]:` else you don't look at the element but at the list itself

Comment: I guess now that I posted this to SO, I kinda see what the issue is.  In the first code block, I'm testing to see if the elements inside lists a/b are truthy.  In the second code block, I'm testing the to see if the lists themselves are truthy...

Comment: I was about to write that as an answer. Please post one @Nuageux

Comment: The error is saying you can't add a float to a None.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `if visitor_team_ratings and home_team_ratings:̀`  you look at the lists.

Whereas if you use: `if visitor_team_ratings[0] and home_team_ratings[0]:`. Then you look at the element inside the lists. (Which correspond to `a` and `b` of your first block)

**edit** I should elaborate more:

```
home_team_ratings = [None]
```

This is the cause of your problem. If you look at the element, it's `None` so the condition won't be True. But if you look at the list, then your `if` will be True since both lists are not empty. But right after `home_team_ratings[0]:` will give an error since it's `None`.

Comment: As soon as I posted this to SO, the light 'clicked on'.  It's amazing, just typing this out for someone else to review helps to actually see the problem.  I'll award you the answer as soon as it available to reward seeing as how you posted 1st in the comments.

Comment: Thanks @Biggen. When you're too much focus on your code, you sometimes don't see the obvious. Usually I'm trying to reproduce my problem on the smallest example possible -as you did-, it is most of the time very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The issues are mainly down to this:

```
home_team_ratings = [None]
```

In the first version, when you write

```
if a and b
```

`b` is `None`, because it came out of `home_team_ratings`. So the `if` condition is false.

In the second version

```
if visitor_team_ratings and home_team_ratings:
```

This condition is true, because neither list is empty.
But then `(home_team_ratings[0] + float(hta))` throws an exception, because you are trying to add `None` to a float.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example `if a and b` evaluates to False, since `bool(None)` is False. In the second example, the list `[None]` evaluates to True, since it is not empty

Answer (score 0):

In the first block, you are looping through the elements of list. Inside the loop, you are evaluating weather elements(a and b both) are true or not. Clearly, None is not true that's why it moves to the else part.

In the second part, you are evaluating whether two lists are true or not. Lists are not empty so if part is executed.